# Double derivative in parametric form

Tags: derivatives, parametric

Let there be two functions expressed in the form of a parametric variable, $y=f(t)$ and $x=g(t)$and I have find the second derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$.

To do that, I have done as shown
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}= \frac{d}{dt}(\frac{dy}{dt})×(\frac{dt}{dx})^2$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{d^2y}{dt^2} \biggm/\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2$$
But I am not getting the correct answer and I don't know what is the problem with this. I want to know if I have done something wrong in the above procedure?

Comment: start with the correct expression for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and differentiate with respect to $x$ using the Chain Rule

Comment: Thanks but i want. To why this one is not working

Comment: see the first solution to this  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2675108/explanation-behind-second-derivative-of-a-parametric-equation-formula?rq=1  to see how it's supposed to be done

Comment: Thanks for it was helpful but i am now wondering that solving the given equation above from right hand side will give me same that is written in left hand side so why this is not working?

Comment: I have added the procedure too

Answer (score 2):

The first expression of yours is wrong

$\displaystyle\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dy}{dx})=\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}})=\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}})\frac{dt}{dx}$ which on evaluating by quotient rule gives

$$\displaystyle\frac{\frac{dx}{dt}.\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}-\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}}{(\frac{dx}{dt})^3}$$

Comment: Thanks but can you tell me why it is wrong

Comment: @Cyberax Because you have used chain rule in a wrong way. You should first calculate first derivative and then second derivative

Comment: Thanks but how i have used it wrong pls can you elaborate briefly.